# Does Firebase throttle multiple REST requests from the same server?

Tags: firebase

We have an application that is running on Heroku and uses Firebase for data. There are some instances where we have to do some logic that require multiple nested Firebase calls (if method 1 succeeds, create object with method 2) and so on. Unfortunately, they seem to be a little more in-depth than what a transaction method on the client side could accomodate.

We are relying on the REST api to do these functions server-side, but have run into issues when stress-testing that they are frequently timing out (especially when issuing a PATCH request).

However, if we run the same test on a different server with the same code and Firebase database, they succeed no problem.

Is there any throttling going on for multiple requests from the same environment?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas